# How to compare two columns of hash table

Tags: perl, hash

I have two CSV files:

#### File1

```
System,name,plan,run
A123,mev,28,12
B123,fsa,31,45
C345,ghd,52,34
```

#### File2

```
System,name,plan,run
A123,mev,20,10
B123,fsa,32,43
C345,ghd,54,34
```

I want to be able to find out which system identifiers are shared by the two files, and of those systems what is the difference between the number of tests 'run'. For example, `File1` and `File2` both have the system `C345` in common, and the difference between their run count is zero (both have 34 run).

My code:

```
my @csv_file = qw| path/tofile1 path/tofile2 |;

opne $f, '<', $csv_file, or die;

foreach $csv_file ( @csv_file ) {

    my %hash;

    while ( my $line = <$f> ) {

        my ($system, $name, $plan, $run) = split(",", $line);
        $hash{$system} = [ $owner, $plan, $run ];

        if ( $run > $plan ) {
            print "More run than planned $system\n"; # prints B123
        }

        if ( $system eq $system ) {
            print "Matching systems: $system\n"; # prints 'System, A123, B123, C345'
        }
    }
}
```

I have been able to print out which systems exist in both files, but cannot figure out how to take those recurring systems and compare their 'run' values with one another.

Comment: You *may* be satisfied that you see where '$run > $plan' (file1,system B123, and in file2, systemB123), and you *may* be happy to see that it displays 6x that systems are matching… but that later is misleading. Your variables are scoped! `%hash` is being (re)defined `foreach $csv_file`, meaning any thing you read in before for `path/tofile1` is gone when you loop over the next `$csv_file`, `path/tofile2`. Same happens with the variables mentioned after the `while …`. You compare `$system eq $system`, that will always be true, like "x" eq "x". You do not check `file1 $system` to `file2 $system`

Answer (score 1):

Normally for this sort of thing, I suggest [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV) and treating the csv files like database tables. But time for something different: using  [Tie::CSV_File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::CSV_File) to make the files look like 2D arrays. Install the module with your favorite CPAN client if your OS's package manager doesn't provide it. (`split` is just not robust enough for general purpose CSV parsing, and there's lots of better options available on CPAN.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Tie::CSV_File;

tie my @file1, "Tie::CSV_File", "file1.csv";
tie my @file2, "Tie::CSV_File", "file2.csv";

my %runs = map { $_->[0] => $_->[3] } @file1[1 .. $#file1];

for my $row (@file2[1 .. $#file2]) {
  my $sys = $row->[0];
  if (exists $runs{$sys}) {
    my $diff = $runs{$sys} - $row->[3];
    say "$sys run difference: $diff";
  }
}
```

Running this on your sample input gives:

```
A123 run difference: 2
B123 run difference: 2
C345 run difference: 0
```

It iterates over the first CSV file, storing the System and run columns as a hash table, and then iterates over the second one, looking up the second one's System in that hash and getting the difference of the two run values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance. Is there any way you could suggest doing this without using a module like DBD::CSV pr Tie::CSV_File? Because as per the criteria, we are not to download any modules through a CPAN client (specific grading rubric ;( ). Hence the fact that I didn't use CSV::Hashify on my code.

Comment: @FranceMadrid You can still use the same basic approach, with your own CSV reading code.